# is it possible to use mvc 4 with oracle 10g

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, oracle10g

I am trying to create a MVC4 application using oracle 10g as database.I have an existing oracle 10g database.
I have searched a lot but did not get a good answer. 
Is it possible to connect oracle database thorough MVC4?
I am new to MVC. Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/using_aspnt.htm#BABJFCDA

Comment: Hi Neel, I am trying to create a MVC4 application. Your link explains about a normal asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.

have a look at this msdn answer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ce9fcec-41df-4954-b913-27d5bb0819eb/entityframework-with-oracle10g-r2?forum=adodotnetentityframework